# Trying to simulate function.bind() on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node **v0.10.28**

I've been trying to simulate the function `bind()` method as a prototype of a function and I've come across a strange issue.

```
Function.prototype.bind = function() {
    var obj = arguments[0],
        argumentsArray = [],
        self = this;

    // since arguments is an object and we can't call .splice() on it
    for(var i in arguments) {
        argumentsArray.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    argumentsArray.splice(0,1);

    // The following throws error when running via node, works fine on browser
    //console.log(argumentsArray); 

    return function() {
        return self.apply(obj,argumentsArray);
    }
};


function sum(y,z) {
    return this.x + y + z; 
}

var obj = { x : 8},
    f, value;

f = sum.bind(obj,1,2);

value = f();

console.log(value);
```

Please refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to0o18b0/1/), when I run in via node ( `node demo.js` ) it has some strange behavior. See the commented `console.log(argumentsArray)` in the fiddle, un-comment that, save it in a file and run via node will give you the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'log'
```

Also the final `console.log(value)` prints nothing on the console when running it via node. The same seems to work perfectly on the browser.

Is there something I'm missing, or node doesn't allows `console.log()` inside of a prototype function definition or anything else?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using `bind()`? Is this an exercise?

Comment: Yes it's just an exercise. Because that's the most fun part about programming, you can do whatever you want ;)

Comment: Interesting, my guess is that for some reason in node `console` relies on `bind` to work. When I renamed your prototype method to `myBind` it works perfectly.

Comment: For improvement: you can use `argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)`, thus eliminating a for lus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because `console` module binds all its methods to itself (see [source here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.28/lib/console.js#L47)). This is for you can do things like:

```
var log = console.log;

log('something');
```

`console` module will be initialize at the first usage. So on line

```
// The following throws error when running via node, works fine on browser
console.log(argumentsArray);
```

`node` will try to initialize `console` module and then call `log` method. In process of module initialization it'll try to bind `log` method to itself [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.28/lib/console.js#L48) and as result - will call your method `bind` again.  `console` module will be considered as initialized, and node will try to call its `log` method. But actually `console` is not initialized at that time. So error will be thrown.

**PS**:

Much simpler realization of what you are trying to do:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(context) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var self = this;

    return function() {
         return self.apply(context, args.concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

Comment: thanks! But why does my implementation still doesn't output any value? I still get nothing when I run it via node. Running this on browser seems to work correctly.

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything because you are not applying arguments of called function

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything `return self.apply(obj,argumentsArray);` must be `return self.apply(obj, argumentsArray.concat([].slice(arguments)))`. See my realization also

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything `node` will use your `bind` method for `console.log`